# Send and Receive an image file with mqtt using ActimeMQ and Spring Consumer

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic, mqtt, spring-jms

I am new to mqtt. I am starting an ActiveMQ server and create a Java Spring Consumer for processing the request. I am successfully publishing a text message from terminal and processd using spring consumer. Next, I need to send an image file through mqtt. I have some questions:

1. Is it possible to send an image file using mqtt?
2. How to receive a file using my Spring Consumer?

This is my java code for consuming mqtt text message:

```
public void onMessage(Message message) {

    if (message instanceof BytesMessage) {
        BytesMessage bm = (BytesMessage) message;
        byte data[];
        data = new byte[(int) bm.getBodyLength()];
        bm.readBytes(data);
        String msgText = new String(data);
    }
}
```

This is my code for sending a file:

```
mosquitto_pub   -d -t test -f /home/abdulmanaf/Pictures/1.png
```

Comment: Did you try it?  What happened if you did, error etc?

Answer (score 0):

code for sending a file:

```
mosquitto_pub   -d -t test -f /home/abdulmanaf/Pictures/1.png
```

Spring Consumer code for receiving a file:

```
if (message instanceof BytesMessage) {
            try {
                BytesMessage bm = (BytesMessage) message;
                byte data[];
                data = new byte[(int) bm.getBodyLength()];
                bm.readBytes(data);

                FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                        "/tmp/hello.png");
                fileOuputStream.write(data);
                fileOuputStream.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```